# How do I hyphenate centered text?

Tags: hyphenation

I am trying to achieve text, that uses hyphentation despite being centered. Apparently this is something non-standard to latex.

Help very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[10]
  \centering
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\centering` does not suppress hyphenation but the penalties and glue are such that it will (almost) always be the case that there is a lower penalty for having a shorter line.

The `ragged2e`  package has `\Centering` which is less flexible at the margins, so more likely to choose hyphenation,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[10]
  \Centering
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```